# Javascript search box not appearing in Domtab

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my website: http://library.bennington.edu. We use domtabs to organize our search boxes. We're switching cataloging software, so I'm trying to replace the catalog search box with a new search box from Ebsco Discovery Services (EDS). EDS provides their own code, so I didn't have to write anything, should just be cut and paste. But when I drop the new code in, nothing appears at all, just a total blank space. If I place the code BELOW the domtabs box, it works fine. It just blanks when placed within the domtabs box, as if there's some conflict. Here's the relevant DomTab code section:

```
<div class="domtab">
<ul class="domtabs">
    <li><a style="border-top-left-radius:9px" href="#catalog">Catalog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#journals">Journals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#databases">Databases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reserves">Reserves</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reference">Reference</a></li>
    <li><a style="border-top-right-radius:9px" href="#archive">Archive</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
    <h2><a name="#catalog" id="catalog"></a></h2>
    <table width="425px">
    <tr>

    <td valign="top" width="70%">
    <!--Insert new code here-->

    <!--Code Ends here-->       
    <span>Search the library's holdings for books, ebooks, movies, music recordings, and more.</span>
    <form action="http://library.bennington.edu/search/Y" method="get" style="display:block; padding: 2px 0px; margin: 0;">     
    <input style="border-radius:3px" type="text" name="SEARCH" size="35" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="SORT" value="A" />
            <script language="javascript">
            function iiiDoSubmit_1() {
                var name = "iiiFormHandle_1";
                if (document.getElementById)
                    obj = document.getElementById(name);
                else if (document.all)
                    obj = document.all[name];
                else if (document.layers)
                    obj = document.layers[name];
                obj.form.submit();
            }

            </script>
            <input type="hidden" id="iiiFormHandle_1"/>
            <a href=# onclick="iiiDoSubmit_1();">
            <input style="border-radius:3px; width:50px; margin-top:3px; padding:2px; font-size:11px" value="Search" type="Submit" />
            </a>
    </form>


    </td>
    <td valign="top" align="right">

    <span class="roundedContentInfo">

    <span style="font-size:130%; border-bottom:1px solid #000; text-align:left;"><b>Other Searches</b></span>
    <span><a href="/search/X">Advanced </a></span>
    <span><a href="/search/t">Title </a></span>
    <span><a href="/search/a">Author </a></span>
    <span><a href="/search/q">Author & Title </a></span>
    </span>

    </td>

    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And here's the code that should be dropped in:

```
<script src="http://support.ebscohost.com/eit/scripts/ebscohostsearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .choose-db-list{ list-style-type:none;padding:0;margin:10px 0 0 0;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:9pt;width:340px; }
    .choose-db-check{ width:20px;float:left;padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px; }
    .choose-db-detail{ margin-left:30px;border-left:solid 1px #E7E7E7;padding:5px 11px 7px 11px;line-height:1.4em; }
    .summary { background-color:#1D5DA7;color:#FFFFFF;border:solid 1px #1D5DA7; }
    .one { background-color: #FFFFFF;border:solid 1px #E7E7E7;border-top:solid 1px #FFFFFF; }
    .two { background-color: #F5F5F5;border:solid 1px #E7E7E7;border-top:solid 1px #FFFFFF; }
    .selected { background-color: #E0EFF7;border:solid 1px #E7E7E7;border-top:solid 1px #FFFFFF; }
    #ebscohostCustomSearchBox #disciplineBlock { width:auto; }
    #ebscohostCustomSearchBox .limiter { float:left;margin:0;padding:0;width:50%; }

    #ebscohostsearchtext { width: 144px; }
    #ebscohostsearchtext.edspub { width: 245px; }

    .ebscohost-search-button.edspub {
        border: 1px solid #156619;
        padding: 5px 10px !important;
        border-radius: 3px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #156619;
    }

    .ebscohost-title.edspub {
        color: #1c7020;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<form id="ebscohostCustomSearchBox" action="" onsubmit="return ebscoHostSearchGo(this);" method="post" style="width:340px; overflow:auto;">
    <input id="ebscohostwindow" name="ebscohostwindow" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="ebscohosturl" name="ebscohosturl" type="hidden" value="http://0-search.ebscohost.com.library.bennington.edu/login.aspx?direct=true&site=eds-live&scope=site&type=0&mode=bool&lang=en&authtype=cookie,ip" />
    <input id="ebscohostsearchsrc" name="ebscohostsearchsrc" type="hidden" value="db" />
    <input id="ebscohostsearchmode" name="ebscohostsearchmode" type="hidden" value="+" />
    <input id="ebscohostkeywords" name="ebscohostkeywords" type="hidden" value="" />

    <div style="background-image:url('http://support.ebscohost.com/images/logos/eds100.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat; height:50px; width:340px; font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:9pt; color:#353535;">
        <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left:115px;">
            <span class="ebscohost-title " style="font-weight:bold;">Research databases</span>

            <div>
                <input id="ebscohostsearchtext" class="" name="ebscohostsearchtext" type="text" size="23"  style="font-size:9pt;padding-left:5px;margin-left:0px;" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="ebscohost-search-button " style="font-size:9pt;padding-left:5px;" />

                <div id="guidedFieldSelectors">
                    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="searchFieldSelector" id="guidedField_0" value="" checked="checked" />
                    <label class="label" for="guidedField_0"> Keyword</label>
                    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="searchFieldSelector" id="guidedField_1" value="TI" />
                    <label class="label" for="guidedField_1"> Title</label>
                    <input class="radio" type="radio" name="searchFieldSelector" id="guidedField_2" value="AU" />
                    <label class="label" for="guidedField_2"> Author</label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="limiterblock" style="margin-left:-px; overflow: auto; ">
        <div id="limitertitle" style="font-weight:bold;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:5px;">Limit Your Results</div>

        <div class="limiter" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkFullText" name="chkFullText" checked="checked" />
            <label for="chkFullText">Full Text</label>
        </div>

        <div class="limiter" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkLibraryCollection" name="chkLibraryCollection"  />
            <label for="chkLibraryCollection">Available in Library Collection</label>
        </div>

        <div class="limiter" style="display:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkPeerReviewed" name="chkPeerReviewed"  />
            <label for="chkPeerReviewed">Peer Reviewed</label>
        </div>

        <div class="limiter" style="display:none;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCatalogOnly" name="chkCatalogOnly"  />
            <label for="chkCatalogOnly">Catalog Only</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

I've moved the javascript call to the top of the page, and moved the CSS to my CSS page to thin out the code, but still just getting the domtab box with normal background color as if nothing is there. :-/